# Changes in spongy urethra during tumescence

Tags: human-anatomy, human-physiology, histology, organs

How does the columnar cells of spongy urethra expand during tumescence(erection of penis)?
If we assume that the urethra has the length, long enough to sustain tumescence without expansion of cells, then will it form wrinkles on retraction just like skin? Probably latter should not be the case, since accumulation of urine would then take place in the grooves of those wrinkles.